# Populating a JComboBox with a selection from another JComboBox

Tags: java, list, object, jcombobox

I’ve got 2 `JComboBoxes`, one displays `Objects` of type `Category` (each `Category` contains a unique `List`) and another to display the `List` in the `Category`.

The aim is to allow a user to select a `Category` in the 1st `JComboBox` and then populate the 2nd `JComboBox` with the `List` appropriate to the user selection.

My current code, before user selection, displays the 1st `JComboBox` with `Objects` of `Category` Type. The 2nd displays the `List` in that `Object`.  *That’s fine.* But upon user selection, the 2nd `JComboBox` doesn’t do anything. It continues to display the same `list` prior to the user selection.

Here is my Code..

```
List<Category> catList = Control.getCatList();
        editItemCatComboBox.removeAllItems();
        for(Category cat: catList) //This populates the 1st JComboBox
        {
            editItemCatComboBox.addItem(cat);

        }
        String selectedCat = editItemCatComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString(); //maybe this line is wrong
        //editItemDialog.validate();
        for (Category cat: catList) //This block should populate the 2nd JComboBox
        {
            if(selectedCat.equals(cat.getCatName()))
            {
                List<Item> itemList = cat.getCatItems();
                editItemItemsComboBox.removeAllItems();
                for(Item itm: itemList)
                {

                    editItemItemsComboBox.addItem(itm);
                }
            }
        }


        editItemDialog.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should implement an ItemListener on the first JCombobox `editItemCatComboBox` that contains the Type `Category` so you can update the second one every time you select a new `Category`

```
editItemCatComboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
        //Update the second JCombobox
    }
});
```